# Starting a 2003 Honda Civic after motor replacement

Tags: engine, honda, civic, no-crank-no-start

We just replaced the motor in my son's 2003 Honda Civic and the key does not turn over the motor.

The same ECU is in the car, however the green light on the dash is on. Does my key need reprogramming, and if so how can I do that myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure on how to reprogram of if you can, but it does sound like the key. You may want to try a second key if you have it.

Comment: Is this the first time you are trying to start it after replacing the engine? Have you ensured all the connections are made correctly? Is it the same starter you had before? Are you getting voltage to the starter? Is there any sound when you turn the key?

Comment: is the car automatic or manual transmission ? did you replace the engine with the same? can it be turned over manually from the front bolt  via socket and ratchet ? did you try using a bypass switch on the starter to see if the starter works on the changed engine? are the ground wires connected?